# How many stars are printed in total by the sequence of operations?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How many stars are printed in total by the sequence
of operations:

`A a = new A(); 
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) a.f(N);`

```
class A
{
  int k = 0;
  void f(int N)
  {
    if (k == 0)
    {
      k = N;
      for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) StdOut.print("*");
    }
      k = k-1;
      StdOut.print("*");
  }
}
```

Would the answer for this question not be O(n)? I am unsure why, but this seems the right for me - when I look at the code. It seems like the for-loop inside the method f only runs on the first call of **a.F(N)** because of the if statement **if(k == 0)** - if the first for-loop was: for (int i=0; i **<=** N; ++i) then the answer would be O(n^2), I think.

Comment: Why not test it? just run the code with a few arbitrary `N` and watch the results.

Comment: Because I am preparing for the exam, where computer is not allowed, so I have to be sure I understand how the code works.

Comment: Then just try to go through the code in your head and see what's the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the method's `for` loop only runs on the first call and prints **N** asterisks. Every call (also the first) also prints one asterisk, so the total of asterisks is **2N**, which is **O(n)**.

If the top loop would run up until **N** included, then **k** would at that last extra call be 0, and so it would be like the first call: **N** extra asterisks are printed, plus the one that is printed for any call.

That makes **3N+1** asterisks, which is still **O(n)**.

#### Snippet (JavaScript)

```js
var N = 200;
var a = new A(); 
for (var i=0; i<N; ++i) a.f(N);
console.log('asterisks: ', a.count);

function A() {
  var k = 0;
  this.count = 0; 
  this.f = function(N)
  {
    if (k == 0)
    {
      k = N;
      for (var i = 0; i<N; ++i) this.count++;
    }
    k = k-1;
    this.count++;
  };
}
```

Output is **400** for **N=200**.